# jQuery image slide in wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an image slide up with jQuery animate on wordpress plugin.

This is my code in custom JavaScript

[website](http://seocenter.xyz/?page_id=14)

```
 $(function(){
    $('.esg-entry-cover').on('mouseover',function(){
    $('.esg-entry-media').find('img').animate({marginTop:($(this).find('img').height()-$(this).height())},1500)
  });
  $('.esg-entry-cover').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.esg-entry-media').find('img').animate({marginTop: ''},1500);
  });
});
```

I want to make an individual slide effect like [this](http://demo.theme-paradise.com/?item=semona-wp)
andI slide at the end is just the height of the image
Thanks for help.

Comment: Define "not working". What errors do you get?

Comment: I mean, maybe my code was wrong.
I'm not sure how to make it.

Comment: I reference this https://jsfiddle.net/pqrnt921/4/ 
So I think it can work.

Comment: Whats your question? are you getting any error? can you elaborate  little bit more and clear?

Comment: There is no error,but I want to write the effect like [this](http://demo.theme-paradise.com/?item=semona-wp)
.When mouse over item, these 3 images will slide up individual and just the height of the image.
Not slide up together.How do I modify the code,or there is other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website outputs the following error in the JavaScript console: `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

This means that `$` is not defined for jQuery and you have to explicitly use jQuery here. So it should be solved when you replace every `$` with `jQuery`.

**Edit**

To animate only the image you hover on, you have to use `this` in the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`. This allows to make changes on only the current element.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.esg-entry-media').on('mouseenter',function(){
        jQuery(this).children('img').animate({marginTop:($(this).find('img').height()-$(this).height())},1500)
    });

    jQuery('.esg-entry-media').on('mouseleave',function(){
        jQuery(this).children('img').animate({marginTop: ''},1500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, there is no error, but this is not what I want. Thanks for help!

Comment: You said that your code wasn't working and I told you why. I'll update my post to make the image slide one-by-one and not all together.